# How does Mplayer interface with external windows?

Tags: linux, x11, mplayer

Here's what happens when I run a file within SMPlayer:

```
       |               |-zsh(7187)---smplayer(8054)-+-mplayer(8061)-+-mplayer(8062)
       |               |                            |               `-{threaded-ml}(8088)
```

This means that SMPlayer ran mplayer as a child process and somehow let it take control over SMPlayer's window. How does this work internally? What trick does SMPlayer use to achieve that? Does it use any library for this purpose that would handle this on Windows as well?

Comment: Sounds like normal inter process communication. Several approaches for this exist. Most likely it creates and uses some local pipes or sockets setup during process spawning.

Comment: Intuition tells me that rendering video through a pipe would be rather slow.